# SetCurrentValue clearing the dependency property under some very specific conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, dependency-properties

**TL;DR:** `SetCurrentValue` unset a dependency property if:

1. The same value as the current one is passed
2. A CoerceValueCallback is given via an override of the metadata of the property.
3. This coerce callback does not change the value
4. There is no binding on the dependency property.

---

I had this issue today that took me a while to fix, but I still don't understand why it happened, so I think it might be worth to ask here. I currently believe it is a bug in the WPF framework.

I have a control, `MyTextBox`, that inherits from the WPF TextBox. It has the following metadata override for the text property:

```
static MyTextBox()
{
    TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, null, CoerceText, true, UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit));
}
```

The `CoerceText` method exists but does not change the base value:

```
private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
{
    return basevalue;
}
```

There is no binding on the `Text` property (Things work if there is one!)

Now suppose I do the following:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var newText = Text;
        SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, newText);
    }
}
```

If I debug this code, `this.Text` becomes `""` (the empty string) after the call to `SetCurrentValue`. However, it should be unchanged.

I ended up by debugging the `SetCurrentValue` method (which is not really debuggable actually...).

That particular test is failing, in `UpdateEffectiveValue` from `DependencyObject.cs`, leading to unsetting the value of the DP. I didn't go any further for my own sanity.

```
if (newEntry.FullValueSource != (FullValueSource) BaseValueSourceInternal.Default)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    UnsetEffectiveValue(entryIndex, dp, metadata);
}
```

Finally, as I said I fixed the problem, and the fix was to remove my own Coerce callback in the overridden metadata:

```
static MyTextBox()
{
    TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, null, null, true, UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit));
}
```

There is no reason to me to explain why by removing the `CoerceValueCallback`, `SetCurrentValue` works as expected and leave the dependency property unchanged instead of clearing it.

So my question is, is there a sane explanation on why this behavior occurs under these specific conditions ?

Comment: For the record, here is the associated Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873193/setcurrentvalue-unset-the-value-under-the-following-circumstances